# Haskell Error Handling

Tags: list, haskell

I have a function that looks up a value from a list of tuples, i'm trying to adapt this function such that if the value isn't in the list of tuples the function identifies it, currently below block of code is throwing error.

```
findint :: String -> [(String,Int)] -> [Int]
findint "" xs = [0]
findint a xs = [y | (x,y) <- xs, x == a]
```

Comment: But here you have a type error: you return a list of `[Int]`s, but your first clause returns an `Int` (not a list of `Int`s).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have edited the code in the question, is this correct now?

Comment: yes, now it will compile. Whether you have to return `[0]` and for instance not an empty list `[]` is of course up to you.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, however, do you have an idea of how I can solve my initial problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using *pattern matching*, for instance with a pattern guard:

```
findint :: String -> [(String,Int)] -> [Int]
findint "" xs = [0]
findint a xs | res@(_:_) <- [y | (x,y) <- xs, x == a] = res
             | otherwise = error "Empty result"
```

So here we check if the list comprehension matches the `(_:_)` pattern. If it does, we return the list, otherwise, we `error`.

We can also perform a `null :: [a] -> Bool` check:

```
findint :: String -> [(String,Int)] -> [Int]
findint "" xs = [0]
findint a xs | null res = error "Empty result"
             | otherwise = res
    where res = [y | (x,y) <- xs, x == a]
```

That being said, usually errors are not the favorite tool of Haskell programmers, since one can not derive these from the signature. Usually a `Maybe` is used for non-total functions:

```
findint :: String -> [(String,Int)] -> Maybe [Int]
findint "" xs = Just [0]
findint a xs | null res = Nothing
             | otherwise = Just res
    where res = [y | (x,y) <- xs, x == a]
```

Now it is clear that if you use this function, there are two possible outcomes: the `Nothing` in case something goes wrong (and thus a caller of the function can handle this seperately), and a `Just x` in case of normal data flow where you unpack the `x` and process it further.

Comment: This is useful, however I may have worded my question poorly. I am not actually looking to throw an exception. I am trying to have the function return something that I can use in an if statement later on to determine where more code should be executed based on the "findint" function finding an item in the list of tuples or not.

Comment: Well this is exactly what you can do with `Maybe` (last part). Here we thus return a `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the behavior you want?

```
Prelude> findInt s = map snd . filter ((== s) . fst)
Prelude> findInt "ohai" [("hello", 0), ("ohai", 2), ("ohai", 3)]
[2,3]
```

No match would return an empty list. I find this reasonable.